# Nav bar not displaying correctly when testing responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I have this page with a nav bar, and on the nav bar, there is a img logo on the left and 3 links on the right. And when I test responsiveness with devices on Chrome, the nav bar resizes and shifts to the left, leaving a blank space on it's right. Here's a picture [Nav bar not displaying fully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMePU.png)

And here is all my code:

```css
    @font-face {
        font-family: coyote;
        src: url(font/coyote.ttf);
    }
    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav {
        background: #efefef;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: -2px -7px 47px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        -moz-box-shadow: -2px -7px 47px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        -webkit-box-shadow: -2px -7px 47px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .logo-section {
        float: left;
        padding: 25px;
        font-family: serif;
    }
    .logo-left {
        width: 12%;
        float: left;
        overflow: none;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        transform: translateY(20%);
    }
    .hb-button {
        float: right;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
        color: black;
        border: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 9px 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
        outline: none;
    }
    nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #282828;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    nav ul {
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0;
        height: 68px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: max-height 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s;
        -o-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    }
    nav ul li {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: coyote;
    }
    li > a {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    li > a:hover {
        color: #CF2034;
        transition: color .7s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
        -o-transition: color .7s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
        -moz-transition: color .7s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
        -webkit-transition: color .7s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    li > a:after {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #CF2034;
        content: "";
        transform: scale(0);
        -o-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
        -moz-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
        -webkit-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
        transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    li > a:hover:after {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    .image-cont {
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 45%;
        min-height: 45%;
        top: 55%;
        left: 50%;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .image {
        animation: load_up 2s forwards;
        -webkit-animation: load_up 2s forwards;
        -moz-animation: load_up 2s forwards;
        -o-animation: load_up 2s forwards;
        margin-top: -50%;
        margin-left: -50%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .image-cont2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        left: 50%;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .image2 {
        display: none;
        animation: load_up 2s forwards;
        -webkit-animation: load_up 2s forwards;
        -moz-animation: load_up 2s forwards;
        -o-animation: load_up 2s forwards;
    }
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 1603px) and (min-device-width: 1081px) {
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        header {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        nav {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            z-index: 99999;
        }
        nav ul li {
            margin 0;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 1080px) {
        .logo-section {
            float: none;
        }
        nav ul {
            background: #ffffff;
            max-height: 0px;
            height: 0;
        }
        nav ul.show {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        nav ul li {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            padding-left: 25%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        nav a {
            display: block;
        }
        .hb-button {
            display: inline;
        }
        .image {
            display: none;
        }
        .image2 {
            display: block;
            margin-top: -35%;
            margin-left: -50%;
        }
        .logo-left {
            transform: translateY(-65%);
            padding-left: 15px;
            width: 10%;
        }
    }
    @keyframes load_up {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(11%);
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes load_up {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(11%);
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes load_up {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(11%);
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    }
    @-o-keyframes load_up {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(11%);
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive_navbar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo-section">
            <button class="hb-button"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div style="min-width: 1920px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/thermocase.png" class="logo-left">
            </a>
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact.html"> &#9679; Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="team.html"> &#9679; The Team</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="product.html"> &#9679; Our Product</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>


<div class="image-cont">
    <img src="img/iphone.png" class="image" />
</div>
<div class="image-cont2">
    <img src="img/iphone2.png" class="image2" />
</div>
```

Thanks for taking a look. Fyi, I'm new to this.

Comment: the issue isn't producible!

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could start with.

You need to have your opening `<body>` tag immediately after your closing `</head>` tag, so you might want to consider using another div to wrap the main content on your page

```
<html>
 <head> ... </head>
 <body>
  <header> ... </header>
   <div class="main-content"> ... </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Secondly, at line 19 of your HTML you have

```
<div style="min-width: 1920px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Hard coding the width of an element like this is going to give you a hard time once the viewport is less that 1920px. You might want to remove this inline CSS, and replace it with a class. Then you can easily manipulate the width of the div using [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), e.g.

HTML

```
<div class="logo-wrap"> ... </div>
```

CSS

```
.logo-wrap{
 ...
}  

@media (min-width: 1920px) {  
 min-width: 1920px; 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Edit**

Try changing your viewport meta tag to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I have followed what you said, but unfortunately it doesn't help me in my question. The nav bar still doesn't display fully.

Comment: Hi @LouisDias, if you create a working codepen or jsbin which illustrates your problem, it will be easier for others to try and help you

Comment: made a codepen: https://codepen.io/Lodi1712/pen/GOXZQp and it works. What i meant is that when I press f12 when previewing my html file on chrome, and I toggle the device mode then responsive, the nav bar shifts to the left. I doesn't do that on codepen when I press f12 and do the same thing. Do you have any guess of what could it be? thanks!

Comment: Does it help if you reload the page in Chrome inspector? Remember that you'll also want to fix the body tag otherwise that will cause problems at some point.

Comment: I think I have found the issue. The viewport. But for the moment I am not able to find the solution. @David

Comment: @LouisDias, your codepen has a typo in the viewport meta tag, not sure if that was there in your original tag though. Please see the alternate viewport meta tag I just posted above